# Show that sentence is not tautology. How many finite models has this sentence?

Tags: logic

Show that sentence $\exists x∃y∃u∃v((¬u=x)∨(¬v=y))∧(f(x,y)=f(u,v))$ is not tautology. How many non-isomorphic finite models has this sentence ?

First of all, I don't understand what does it mean: $\neg u, \neg v$. What is $u$ ? What is $\neg u$ ?

Comment: Perhaps $\neg u=x$ means $\neg(u=x)$?

Comment: Hmm, I think that you are right. Then, can you give me a hint ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience in this domain.

Comment: It's not a tautology because it's false in a model with a one-element domain. The number of nonisomorphic finite models is obviously $\aleph_0.$ Are you sure the problem didn't ask for the number of nonisomorphic $n$-element models, for each finite $n?$ That number would be $0$ for $n=1$ and $n^{n^2}$ for $n\gt0.$

Answer (score 0):

To prove that it is not a tautology, you just need a structure where it is false. For this, you just need a structure that assigns to $f$ an injective function, so no two distinct pairs of the universe map to the same element. As bof pointed out an example would be $f : (x,y) \mapsto 2^{x}3^{y}$, with $\mathbb{N}$ the universe, say.

Comment: What do you mean exactly ? What does it mean finite model here ? After all, model here is domain and function.

Comment: Yes, the model is the domain and function. Usually though one uses "finite (or infinite, etc...) model" as shorthand for "model with finite (or infinite, etc...) domain/universe".

Comment: I am not sure If I correctly understand you: your sum expresses number of injective function on finite domain $U$. Yeah ?

Comment: Yes, that sum there is supposed to be the number of nontotal injections $U^{2} \to U$ with $|U| > 1$. It was supposed to show that for each $n > 1$ there are finitely many models of size $n$, thus only denumerably (countably infinitely) many models of finite size. The formula itself is not really important (perhaps I should've ommitted it).

Comment: Thanks, the problem is getting clear. Can you edit your post and add information about: non-isomorphism (from what we know, and what does it mean non-isomorphic). And why you think that $f$ can't be total (total for me is defined on the whole domain)

Comment: I edited the post, is it clear now why $f$ can't be total? Think about what happens if it were both total and injective. I deleted the second part because I think I might have made a mistake on that formula, now that I consider it more carefully, sorry.

Comment: So, what about non-isomorphism. Can you tell something about it ?

Comment: If $f(x,y)=x^y$ then $f(2,4)=f(4,2)=f(16,1).$ A better example might be $f(x,y)=2^x3^y$ or $f(x,y)=2^{x-1}(2y-1).$

Comment: Oh! Down know how I missed that!